Options after breaking USB-C jack off of PCB

Hello!
Snapped the USB-C jack off of my Logitech MX Keys.
I have a background in computer engineering and some experience doing board-level repairs.  I do have an SMD hotplate, multiple soldering irons, and wire and other bits and pieces.
Some observations:

One of the PCB traces of the roughly 14 fingers that attach the jack to the PCB seems to have lifted (a little left of the tip of the orange arrow)
There are contact points, that I'm assuming are the + and - power from the charging cable (green and pink arrows)

Options I'm considering to repair:

Least effort, least convenient long-term: remove the battery and charge it outside of the keyboard
Medium effort, ugly: figure out where on the PCB the + and - traces run to, solder wires to those, run the wires out of the hole where the USB C port once was
Most difficult, actual repair: make sure that one PCB trace that lifted wasn't being used, try and find a jack that matches the pinout of the one I snapped off, remove PCB and reflow.

What would you do?

This is such a clean break it would be fairly easy to solder a new connector on if you've done any SMD soldering. Higher resolution image would confirm it, but probably the pad ripped off since it wasn't connected to anything given this is a wireless keyboard.

why is the area of interest less that 1% of the picture

I would attempt a repair.  So long as you’re comfortable soldering SMD parts , you don’t have much to lose.

@user1850479 thank you for the insight.  I'm open to it, effort would go into finding one that fits the trace, but maybe it's not difficult.  I'll peruse Mauser, Digi and Ali.
Will try and get you a better photo with a DSLR and macro lens if I remember next I'm at work.
I agree!! Good change I'll get lucky.  Thank you.

@jsotola I took closer pictures but could only figure out how to upload one.  I'll try and upload another.  Main issue is I don't know how to make the 13 Mini do macro shots.  It has trouble focusing at that focal distance where my older 5-8 didn't.

@EricEverton thank you for the perspective.  I am.  That's a great point; try the most comprehensive solution because doing so doesn't negate a backup option.  Thank you.
